# How to copy an array using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

If I have the following byte array:

```
byte[] someArray = new byte { 0, 1, 2 };
```

and I want to copy it to an instance of a class through reflection, how can you do that?

```
// Inside a class method

PropertyInfo property = this.GetType().GetProperty("propertyName");

if(property.PropertyType == typeof(System.Byte[]))
{
    property.SetValue(this, ???, ???); // How to set an array?
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Array.Clone()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clone.aspx):

```
if(property.PropertyType == typeof(System.Byte[]))
{
    property.SetValue(this, someArray.Clone(), null); 
}
```

Comment: Is the third parameter optional?

Comment: .NET 4.5 added an overload that takes only 2 parameters.  I have added the third parameter to be backwards-compatible.

Comment: Great, thanks.  I was wondering about the "pointer" and this takes care of it :)

Comment: The only thing to note is that the Array.Clone method is a shallow copy, so if you end up using reference types at some future point, the new array will point to the same objects that the original array did.